# Can someone help me, tell me the meaning of this code?

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth

I tried to modify the Wiimote Whiteboard app for my final project. 
but my experience in the programming language C # is very little.

I do not know what is the meaning of a few lines of code: 
can anyone help me?

```
    [DllImport("bthprops.cpl", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr BluetoothFindFirstDevice(ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS SearchParams, ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO DeviceInfo);

    [DllImport("bthprops.cpl", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool BluetoothFindNextDevice(IntPtr hFind, ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO DeviceInfo);

    [DllImport("bthprops.cpl", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool BluetoothFindDeviceClose(IntPtr hFind);

    [DllImport("bthprops.cpl", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint BluetoothSetServiceState(IntPtr hRadio, ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO DeviceInfo, ref Guid guid, int ServiceFlags);

    [DllImport("bthprops.cpl", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint BluetoothRemoveDevice(ref BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS Address);
```

I am very grateful if you are willing to help me. 
I am looking for someone who has mastered the C # programming language to guide me in this project. 
I hope someone is willing to help me. 
I am sorry for my english is very weak.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
I now know, this is used to call methods from bthprops.cpl. 
But I want to know what the purpose of each of the code, I hope you are willing to help me.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362927(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Whether the iteration process is stopped when it was discovered bluetooth devices in accordance with the description in BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO or enumerate all bluetooth devices?
In the fourth code if the Bluetooth device servis is started, based on the description BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO or by GUID?
sorry my english is weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statements that you have shown are importing function entry points from a DLL. These function entry points are all "C" language calls. The DLL in this case is called: "bthprops.cpl". Which is the windows Blue Tooth control panel control.

In each case the statement specifies the name of the DLL followed by a declaration of the function signature. For example:

```
static extern IntPtr BluetoothFindFirstDevice(ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS SearchParams, ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO DeviceInfo);
```

The effect of these DLLImport statements is that the  function is now callable from within your C# application. In this case it is a function that allows you to start iterating over all Blue Tooth devices.

Comment: Thank you Peter for the explanation. 
so the first method to start the iteration bluetooth devices. 
and the second to find the next bluetooth device. 
the third to close the iteration process. 
whether the iteration process is stopped when it was discovered bluetooth devices in accordance with the description in BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO or enumerate all bluetooth devices? 
And what was done in the fourth code? I am sorry for my english is very weak.

Comment: You can find all the details about these functions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362927(v=vs.85).aspx